# Modification to WhatsApp apk

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, customization

So, basically I wanted to modify the looks of my WhatsApp (WhatsApp 2.12.317) application in my Android. This is what I have done:

1.Decompiled the APK using apktool 2.0.2

2.Did the necessary editings.(mostly in strings.xml and colors.xml and a few PNGs)

3.Recompiled the APK

4.Signed it using APK signer

Problem arises when I install and run my modded whatsapp. The SMS verification step fails. When I go for the "Call Me" option it says "Client has been modified ....". So what do I do? Did i go wrong somewhere? Plz help.

Comment: This question may possibly be off-topic as Android Enthusiasts does not cover Android development. I suspect that WhatsApp run server-side verification to make sure that people do not run modified clients but I cannot be sure. If this is the case, I do not know whether this can be fixed.

Comment: Sounds like it is compiled in a manner where it will not let you modify the original APK file, and will cause errors.

Comment: WhatsApp has a history with unofficial clients [in the past](http://www.androidcentral.com/whatsapp-cracks-down-users-of-unofficial-clients).  My guess is that the developers built some sort of authenticity check into the application to ensure only unmodified official clients are connecting to their network.  Your modifications  cause this test to fail, and you will not be able to fix this without knowing the authentication logic.

Comment: Is it the unofficial signature of mine that causes it??

Answer (score 0):

The resigning signs the apk with a new certificate, but not the original from WhatsApp. If that was possible nobody would create commercial software for Android as it would be too easy to hack.

Google play services have a number of measurements in place to discover modified APKs, and the error you see simply means WhatsApp is using them.

Comment: Hm.. I get it. This means I need to find a way to stop the communication between Whatsapp and Google Play services. What if I uninstall Google Play services? Will it work?

Comment: Then it will probably fail with a message saying you need Play Services... The whole idea of this protection is to stop people from using a modified APK.  In theory you should be able to modify the compiled code such that it disables the checks, but I think it is a lot of work to find all places where the results are checked.